# Cross-compiling rust with cargo tries to link with host libs

Tags: rust, x86-64, cross-compiling, freebsd, arm64

I'm trying to cross-compile a crate from a FreeBSD 13.1 x86_64 host to a FreeBSD 13.1 aarch64 target. I have already succeeded in cross-compiling my crate from FreeBSD 12.1 x86_64 to FreeBSD 12.1 aarch64.

To do so, I have the following environment:

```
cargo version
cargo 1.67.0-nightly (f6e737b1e 2022-12-02)

rustc --version
rustc 1.67.0-nightly (01fbc5ae7 2022-12-07)

export AARCH64_SYSROOT=/path/to/aarch64/root
export PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR=$AARCH64_SYSROOT
export RUSTFLAGS="-C link-args=-fuse-ld=lld -C link-args=-L$AARCH64_SYSROOT/usr/lib -C link-args=-L$AARCH64_SYSROOT/lib -C link-args=-L$AARCH64_SYSROOT/usr/local/lib -C link-args=--sysroot=$AARCH64_SYSROOT"
```

The command I run to build is the following, and I get this error on FreeBSD 13.1:

```
cargo build -Z build-std --release --target aarch64-unknown-freebsd

ld.lld: error: /usr/local/lib/libssl.so is incompatible with $AARCH64_SYSROOT/usr/lib/Scrt1.o
ld.lld: error: /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so is incompatible with $AARCH64_SYSROOT/usr/lib/Scrt1.o
ld.lld: error: /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so is incompatible with $AARCH64_SYSROOT/usr/lib/Scrt1.o
cc: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It looks like the linker is trying to link with my host libraries even though I specify the link paths in `RUSTFLAGS`.

I ran cargo with the `--verbose` flags on both machines and saw that `-L native=/usr/local/lib` appears on FreeBSD 13.1 but `-L native=$AARCH64_SYSROOT/usr/local/lib` is shown on FreeBSD 12.1 so I think this is a pretty big clue but I might be completly wrong.

Why does my host libs path appear on FreeBSD13 but not on FreeBSD12 ? How can I remove this default flags when running my `cargo build` command ?

I tried invoking rustc directly with the command shown by `cargo build --verbose` (removing the `-L native=/usr/local/lib` option) which seems to work. However this is not practical as my crate has many dependencies and building properly without using cargo would be a mess...

Comment: Not too familiar with Rust, but I suspect that the linker receives arguments from something else that is not sysroot aware. If it's `rustc` doing it, setting `--sysroot` on it directly should fix that. If it's something in the build system that calls `pkg-config` or whatever, then you might have to set env vars to redirect that to work with your sysroot.

Answer (score 0):

You should not rely on `-I` and `-L` to locate your cross libraries (which will only add foreign libraries to your set of host libraries, creating a mix), but rather instruct the toolchain to use the cross sysroot instead of the host sysroot.

This can be done as [described in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74830994/cross-compile-rust-for-raspberry-pi-with-sysroot).

Note that for cross-compiling using Linux containers, the [cross-rs](https://github.com/cross-rs/cross/) projects has turnkey containers with toolchain and base sysroot.  They could possibly be adapted to create Jails containers?